# Batch Script, need help generating lines of six different numbers (between 1 and 39) that have no more than 2 numbers in common with any previous line

Tags: sorting, batch-file, duplicates, batch-processing

Batch Script, need help generating lines of six different numbers that have no more than 2 numbers in common with any previous line

The goal is to generate a csv file of 300 sets of 6 random numbers between 1 and 39, each set of 6 on a separate line, and each line with a maximum of two numbers in common with any previous line (two numbers with any one line of all previous lines).  That's the goal.  I've hit a snag.  I'm hoping someone might see an easier way.

The script I've made (pieced together) generates a list file without repetition in the row, but the row itself gets longer and longer instead of cutting off at 6.  I also still need the part that checks all previous rows to ensure a max of two duplicates.  If someone has a workaround (a sincere one), I greatly appreciate any to help reach the goal sooner.

Here's the script so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

for /L %%j in (1 1 10) do (
    call:get_rand
    echo %%j  ;!NUM[1]!;!NUM[2]!;!NUM[3]!;!NUM[4]!;!NUM[5]!;!NUM[6]! >> test.txt

    sort "get_six.txt" >> "get_sort.txt"
    for /f %%b in (get_sort.txt) do findstr "%%~b" "get_tmp.txt" >nul 2>&1 || echo %%b>>"get_tmp.txt"
    call:get_horiz
rem call:del_get_files
)
goto:EOF


rem delete extra files:
rem :del_get_files
rem for %%z in (get_six.txt,get_sort.txt,get_tmp.txt) do (
rem     if exist "%%z" del /q /f "%%z"
rem )
rem goto:EOF


rem get_tmp.txt vertical list to csv horizontal list.txt
:get_horiz
set var=
for /f "tokens=*" %%c in (get_tmp.txt) do (
    call set var=%%var%%,%%c
)
SET var=%var:~1%
echo !var! >> list.txt
goto:EOF


rem get first set of six random numbers
:get_rand
for /L %%i in (1 1 6) do (
    call:get_n %%i
    rem get random number, 1 is the min, 39 is the max
    echo !num[%%i]! >> get_six.txt
)
goto:EOF


rem get random num[%%i] between 1 and 39
:get_n
set /a num[%1] = %RANDOM% * 39 / 32768 + 1
goto:EOF
```

==========

```
list.txt (expected):

03,11,17,24,28,37
11,13,25,26,36,39
02,09,15,23,28,37
03,13,14,26,28,32
08,11,21,22,34,36
02,13,16,26,27,31
01,06,14,20,27,31
07,09,20,23,33,34
...
```

Condition 1: no duplicate numbers per line

Condition 2: not matching more than two numbers with any other line

(I've only checked these visually, I might have missed some, but, for example, the fourth line "03,13,14,26,28,32" has 03 and 28 in common with the first line, "03,11,17,24,28,37", and 13 and 26 with the second, "11,13,25,26,36,39"--that's ok, it's within the permitted maximum)

```
list.txt (current):

10,28,39 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36,25,34,35 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36,25,34,35,18,31,32 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36,25,34,35,18,31,32,19,29,7 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36,25,34,35,18,31,32,19,29,7,11,17,21,23,33 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36,25,34,35,18,31,32,19,29,7,11,17,21,23,33,12,37 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36,25,34,35,18,31,32,19,29,7,11,17,21,23,33,12,37,24 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36,25,34,35,18,31,32,19,29,7,11,17,21,23,33,12,37,24,15 
10,28,39,14,20,22,36,25,34,35,18,31,32,19,29,7,11,17,21,23,33,12,37,24,15,27
```

:/

Comment: Mind sharing the expected results as an example, also, the current results?

Comment: Second question (related):

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76236731/batch-script-amending-a-working-script-that-generates-sets-of-random-numbers-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="

SET #combos=0

:newcombo
SET /a #nums=0
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="
:newrnd
SET /a nextrand=%RANDOM%
IF %nextrand% gtr 32759 GOTO newrnd
SET /a nextrand=101+(nextrand%%39)
IF DEFINED $%nextrand% GOTO newrnd
SET "$%nextrand%=%nextrand:~-2%"
SET /a #nums+=1
IF %#nums% lss 6 GOTO newrnd
SET "#c="
FOR  /F "tokens=2delims==" %%e In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "#c=!#c!,%%e"
FOR /L %%y IN (1,1,%#combos%) DO (
 SET /a matchcount=0
 FOR %%o IN (!#c%%y!) DO IF DEFINED $1%%o set/a matchcount+=1
 IF !matchcount! gtr 2 GOTO newcombo
)
SET /a #combos+=1

ECHO %#combos% generated

SET "#c%#combos%=%#c:~1%"
IF %#combos% lss 300 GOTO newcombo
(
 FOR /L %%y IN (1,1,%#combos%) DO ECHO !#c%%y!
)>u:\combos.txt

TYPE u:\combos.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Well - it'll not break any speed records. Overnight run - at least.

Set a new random into `nextrand`. Check that it is not >32759 as values over this would bias the processed random number (which isn't linear in any case)

Calculate 101+(random mod 39) -> 101..139

if `$selection` is set, then that number has already been chosen, so choose again. Otherwise, set `$selection` to `01`..`39`.

repeat until we have chosen 6 numbers

Build `#c` from $valuesselected values, which will be in sorted order (characteristic of `set`) and insert commas before each, so `#c` might become `,05,07,12,17,22,31` for instance

for each combination already recorded, count the number of matches against the current set of 6 `$1xx` values chosen. If more than 2 are found, find another combo. Otherwise, record the new combination and count until the limit is reached.

But - it really is slow...

Comment: thank you!  I've change the 2nd and 3rd last lines of the code, removed "u:\" to keep the new combos.txt file in the same directory as the .bat file

Comment: I'll try to speed the process by simply running through all the (39 choose 6) combinations, looping each number from 1 through 39 instead of a random sampling, then take a random completed line from the completed file.  That'll also tell me how many possible sets there even are (of the 3,262,623 total 6-number combinations).  I'm specifically curious how many have just 1 repeated number--whether it's indeed 247.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I believe you'll find that the second version is fast enough to now warrant more optimisation.

Comment: I'd suggest you try the second code. For 300 combinations, it ran for me in 42 seconds. The first was up to about 150 in 3 hours. No need to translate to Python. I've no idea where your statistics are coming from. How is 247 calculated for instance?

Comment: I'll delete that second script as it doesn't do what I expected. I've experimented with a number of different implementations of recording which number pair have been used, but all resulted in the process slowing rapidly.

Comment: Magoo, sincerely, thank you.  The first script is really perfect.  Speed wasn't ever necessary in this, time there is plenty.  The second was a truly inspired idea, but really the first is perfect.  You nailed it spot on!  Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253616/discussion-between-rene-and-magoo).

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm... Your problem seems simple at first, but it's not at all!

Before try to write any code, let's analyze the problem for a moment.

The "base set" are the first 39 natural numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

How many *different* sets of 6 numbers with no repetitions can be assembled from this base set? It seems that is just 6. How many sets with 1 repetition can be assembled? It seems that some multiple of 7 (I am not good enough with mathemathics). My point is that I really doubt that with a max of 2 repetitions could be assembled 300 sets... Perhaps someone with better math knowledge could give us an exact answer, but if the answer is less than 300, then any program will never stop no matters the method used to write it.

On the other hand, the problem is complex and convoluted to solve. Suppose we develop a method to create sets of 6 numbers with a max of 2 repetitions and we create 50 sets. Then, after we create the set # 51, there are *3 numbers* that are the same than in another previously generated set. What we must do now? We could eliminate *one* of the 3 repeated elements in the new set and insert the next valid number in that place. However, depending on *which one* element be eliminated, the final result could be very different...

We should *save the state* of all sets up to that moment, continue generating sets and check if we could generate the required 300. If not, then we should *backtrack* to that state, eliminate *another number* of the repeated 3 and repeat the process again until the end. In this way, this method to solve this problem is similar to the one for *chess game* (my code below does *not* use any backtracking). You should also consider that this method would require a *huge number* of data movements, so the program must be designed with **optimization** as the primary goal; otherwise (or anyway) the program will run for several hours for sure...

Below is my first attempt to solve this problem in a suitable way. I don't generate random numbers one by one until collect the non-repeated 6. Instead, I use an array with the 39 numbers placed in 39 succesive elements. Then, I randomly (1-39) select one of them and move to that place the last (39th) number and decrease the "number of numbers" count to 38. For the second number I do the same: randomly (1-38) select a number, move to that place the 38th number and decrease the counter. In this way I can generate 6 non-repeated numbers in random order in just 6 cycles via 6 random numbers.

(Question: why the numbers must be generated in random *order*? When the results are displayed the numbers are sorted in natural order again.)

I also store the generated numbers as **indices** of arrays (not as *values*). This point allows me to test numbers via the simpler "if defined element[%num%] ..." that run faster than the usual "if !element[%index%]! equ %num% ..."

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


rem The 300 lines are generated as a 2-dimensional matrix called "n" with this shape:
rem    n[%line%][%num%]=1
rem Where "line" is the index of the line: from 1 to 300
rem and "num" is *each number* (value between 1 and 39) that comprise such a line
rem
rem Each new line is previously generated in "num" array with 6 elements in the same way


rem Randomize
for /L %%i in (0,1,%time:~-1%) do set "x=!random!"

rem Generate 300 lines with 6 numbers each
set "line=0"
set "num[0]=0"
:nextLine

   rem Set numbers 1..39 as "available"
   for /L %%i in (1,1,39) do set "avail[%%i]=%%i"
   set "numsAvail=39"

   rem Remove previously generated numbers
   for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%n in ('set num[') do set "num[%%n]="
   set "numbers=0"

   rem Generate 6 random numbers (from "available" ones):

   rem Get the index of anyone (random  order) of available numbers
   rem Insert such available number in "num" array
   rem Move to the (position of the) used available number the *last one*, and eliminate (the last) one available number
   rem And pass to the next number
   :nextAvail
      set /A indexAvail=%random% %% numsAvail + 1
      set /A num[!avail[%indexAvail%]!]=avail[%indexAvail%], avail[%indexAvail%]=avail[%numsAvail%], numsAvail-=1, numbers+=1
   if %numbers% lss 6 (
      if %numsAvail% gtr 0 (
         goto nextAvail
      ) else (
         goto nextLine
      )
   )

   rem Compare the new 6 numbers vs. *all* previously generated lines
   rem and eliminate the (last) number that cause to have more than 2 repeated numbers:

   for /L %%i in (1,1,%line%) do (
      set "repeated=0"
      for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%j in ('set num[') do (
         if defined n[%%i][%%j] set /A repeated+=1
         if !repeated! gtr 2 (
            set "num[%%j]="
            set /A numbers-=1
            if %numsAvail% gtr 0 (
               goto nextAvail
            ) else (
               goto nextLine
            )
         )
      )
   )

   rem Insert (and show) the new line:
   set /A line+=1
   < NUL (
   set /P "=%time:~0,-3%  %line%- "
   for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%n in ('set num[') do (
      set "n[%line%][%%n]=1"
      set /P "=%%n "
   ))
   echo/

if %line% lss 300 goto nextLine
```

I run this code for 1 hour and 50 minutes in my old-and-slow machine until it generates 100 sets. Obviously, the first sets are generated very fast and the time increases with the number of sets. This is the listing of the first 100 results:

```
21:52:36  1- 15 18 21 34 5 6
21:52:36  2- 10 14 15 26 33 6
21:52:36  3- 13 16 25 30 32 33
21:52:36  4- 14 23 29 2 35 39
21:52:36  5- 14 25 27 34 36 4
21:52:37  6- 12 18 20 22 36 7
21:52:37  7- 12 20 21 24 27 37
21:52:37  8- 22 28 30 35 6 9
21:52:38  9- 12 18 28 35 38 5
21:52:38  10- 18 23 25 30 36 8
21:52:39  11- 15 17 24 3 5 8
21:52:39  12- 17 22 24 26 29 31
21:52:40  13- 21 2 32 37 39 7
21:52:41  14- 11 23 28 2 33 7
21:52:41  15- 16 19 1 30 34 36
21:52:43  16- 15 21 32 38 4 9
21:52:43  17- 12 21 25 33 34 39
21:52:44  18- 16 24 32 6 8 9
21:52:46  19- 12 1 27 35 36 8
21:52:48  20- 15 18 20 33 35 3
21:52:49  21- 11 14 18 28 34 37
21:52:51  22- 20 22 25 26 35 39
21:52:53  23- 10 11 26 34 35 38
21:52:54  24- 18 19 22 28 2 39
21:52:56  25- 12 16 20 30 31 5
21:52:57  26- 15 16 23 27 36 6
21:52:59  27- 10 12 23 32 39 4
21:53:09  28- 17 23 26 28 34 4
21:53:11  29- 16 17 1 25 26 9
21:53:14  30- 12 13 15 16 2 7
21:53:15  31- 10 20 24 2 36 3
21:53:20  32- 10 11 17 1 20 23
21:53:24  33- 11 13 15 20 21 22
21:53:28  34- 14 15 20 28 29 36
21:53:30  35- 15 16 18 19 25 31
21:53:33  36- 10 15 17 18 32 37
21:53:47  37- 11 14 15 25 2 32
21:53:49  38- 19 21 28 7 8 9
21:53:55  39- 11 1 22 24 27 30
21:53:58  40- 10 14 18 20 30 4
21:54:01  41- 1 21 26 27 28 39
21:54:03  42- 10 13 25 34 6 9
21:54:04  43- 19 23 27 30 33 38
21:54:17  44- 10 12 13 18 27 3
21:54:25  45- 11 18 26 29 30 32
21:54:28  46- 13 14 15 37 38 39
21:54:30  47- 14 18 1 23 3 9
21:54:36  48- 12 13 20 23 28 6
21:54:48  49- 11 15 1 26 7 8
21:55:05  50- 11 12 13 17 26 39
21:55:10  51- 11 18 21 24 35 36
21:55:23  52- 10 12 15 29 38 8
21:55:46  53- 10 11 12 14 5 7
21:55:50  54- 13 26 27 2 33 36
21:55:58  55- 16 17 20 22 34 37
21:56:20  56- 10 11 13 31 33 4
21:56:23  57- 13 18 29 2 4 5
21:56:25  58- 1 22 23 2 31 5
21:56:30  59- 14 16 17 19 35 6
21:56:53  60- 10 12 16 17 21 36
21:57:29  61- 13 1 20 25 5 7
21:57:51  62- 10 14 17 24 25 38
21:58:03  63- 11 13 14 16 1 29
21:58:13  64- 10 15 16 28 30 39
21:58:20  65- 10 16 19 37 3 4
21:59:37  66- 10 11 21 25 37 8
21:59:40  67- 19 1 28 31 38 3
21:59:46  68- 15 25 26 27 30 3
22:00:10  69- 11 12 19 20 3 8
22:01:36  70- 11 13 30 35 3 7
22:02:09  71- 24 29 34 4 6 7
22:03:36  72- 24 26 35 37 7 9
22:05:18  73- 11 12 15 24 28 4
22:05:41  74- 22 23 24 33 34 36
22:07:15  75- 12 17 1 30 33 7
22:07:17  76- 19 25 32 4 5 6
22:07:35  77- 10 12 19 1 22 6
22:07:57  78- 12 14 15 17 22 23
22:08:57  79- 10 11 19 27 32 36
22:08:59  80- 11 25 31 36 5 9
22:10:39  81- 13 1 22 26 32 3
22:11:41  82- 11 12 22 29 33 35
22:11:54  83- 12 14 24 31 34 8
22:15:02  84- 12 13 14 19 30 9
22:17:18  85- 10 19 24 28 29 33
22:19:24  86- 17 1 24 37 39 6
22:21:04  87- 11 16 17 18 27 33
22:21:14  88- 12 1 20 2 32 38
22:22:37  89- 11 16 22 38 39 7
22:22:50  90- 10 18 1 29 31 39
22:27:39  91- 15 17 19 1 27 2
22:29:04  92- 13 19 21 23 24 2
22:36:51  93- 12 14 32 33 36 3
22:43:11  94- 13 18 20 24 31 32
22:53:34  95- 16 18 20 21 23 38
23:00:23  96- 11 14 30 31 38 6
23:02:39  97- 10 1 27 34 37 7
23:04:17  98- 13 16 17 23 31 3
23:08:38  99- 19 20 21 29 31 4
23:42:58  100- 10 12 26 28 31 37
```

I know there are several "cosmetic" details that had not been solved yet in my code, but IMHO it is much more important to clearly define the problem's solution first, before waste more CPU time in a not useful code...

Perhaps a *much simpler solution* would be to generate *all* sets of 6 numbers with up to 2 repeated elements (that can be generated under precise rules in a very fast way) and then randomly choose 300 from those sets... I am currently working in such a solution.

---

**EDIT**: *First two parts of new solution are ready*

The first two parts of the new solution are ready: sets of 6 numbers with NO and with ONE repetitions. Only the part with TWO repetitions is missing.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A last=39, n=6, nM1=n-1

echo Combinations of 6 numbers with No repetitions:
set /A lastI=(last/n-1)*n+1, count=0
< NUL (
for /L %%i in (1,%n%,%lastI%) do (
   set /A lastJ=%%i+nM1
   for /L %%j in (%%i,1,!lastJ!) do (
      set /P "=%%j "
   )
   echo/
   set /A count+=1
))
echo Total = %count%

echo/
echo Combinations of 6 numbers with ONE repetition:
set /A lastI=last-(n-1)*2, count=0
< NUL (
for /L %%i in (1,1,%lastI%) do (
   set /A "firstJ=%%i+1, lastJ=firstJ+((last-firstJ+1)/nM1-1)*nM1"
   for /L %%j in (!firstJ!,%nM1%,!lastJ!) do (
      set /P "=%%i "
      set /A lastK=%%j+n-2
      for /L %%k in (%%j,1,!lastK!) do (
         set /P "=%%k "
      )
      echo/
      set /A count+=1
   )
))
echo Total = %count%
```

Output:

```
Combinations of 6 numbers with No repetitions:
1 2 3 4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 
Total = 6

Combinations of 6 numbers with ONE repetition:
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 7 8 9 10 11 
1 12 13 14 15 16 
1 17 18 19 20 21 
1 22 23 24 25 26 
1 27 28 29 30 31 
1 32 33 34 35 36 
2 3 4 5 6 7 
2 8 9 10 11 12 
2 13 14 15 16 17 
2 18 19 20 21 22 
2 23 24 25 26 27 
2 28 29 30 31 32 
2 33 34 35 36 37 
3 4 5 6 7 8 
3 9 10 11 12 13 
3 14 15 16 17 18 
3 19 20 21 22 23 
3 24 25 26 27 28 
3 29 30 31 32 33 
3 34 35 36 37 38 
4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 10 11 12 13 14 
4 15 16 17 18 19 
4 20 21 22 23 24 
4 25 26 27 28 29 
4 30 31 32 33 34 
4 35 36 37 38 39 
5 6 7 8 9 10 
5 11 12 13 14 15 
5 16 17 18 19 20 
5 21 22 23 24 25 
5 26 27 28 29 30 
5 31 32 33 34 35 
6 7 8 9 10 11 
6 12 13 14 15 16 
6 17 18 19 20 21 
6 22 23 24 25 26 
6 27 28 29 30 31 
6 32 33 34 35 36 
7 8 9 10 11 12 
7 13 14 15 16 17 
7 18 19 20 21 22 
7 23 24 25 26 27 
7 28 29 30 31 32 
7 33 34 35 36 37 
8 9 10 11 12 13 
8 14 15 16 17 18 
8 19 20 21 22 23 
8 24 25 26 27 28 
8 29 30 31 32 33 
8 34 35 36 37 38 
9 10 11 12 13 14 
9 15 16 17 18 19 
9 20 21 22 23 24 
9 25 26 27 28 29 
9 30 31 32 33 34 
9 35 36 37 38 39 
10 11 12 13 14 15 
10 16 17 18 19 20 
10 21 22 23 24 25 
10 26 27 28 29 30 
10 31 32 33 34 35 
11 12 13 14 15 16 
11 17 18 19 20 21 
11 22 23 24 25 26 
11 27 28 29 30 31 
11 32 33 34 35 36 
12 13 14 15 16 17 
12 18 19 20 21 22 
12 23 24 25 26 27 
12 28 29 30 31 32 
12 33 34 35 36 37 
13 14 15 16 17 18 
13 19 20 21 22 23 
13 24 25 26 27 28 
13 29 30 31 32 33 
13 34 35 36 37 38 
14 15 16 17 18 19 
14 20 21 22 23 24 
14 25 26 27 28 29 
14 30 31 32 33 34 
14 35 36 37 38 39 
15 16 17 18 19 20 
15 21 22 23 24 25 
15 26 27 28 29 30 
15 31 32 33 34 35 
16 17 18 19 20 21 
16 22 23 24 25 26 
16 27 28 29 30 31 
16 32 33 34 35 36 
17 18 19 20 21 22 
17 23 24 25 26 27 
17 28 29 30 31 32 
17 33 34 35 36 37 
18 19 20 21 22 23 
18 24 25 26 27 28 
18 29 30 31 32 33 
18 34 35 36 37 38 
19 20 21 22 23 24 
19 25 26 27 28 29 
19 30 31 32 33 34 
19 35 36 37 38 39 
20 21 22 23 24 25 
20 26 27 28 29 30 
20 31 32 33 34 35 
21 22 23 24 25 26 
21 27 28 29 30 31 
21 32 33 34 35 36 
22 23 24 25 26 27 
22 28 29 30 31 32 
22 33 34 35 36 37 
23 24 25 26 27 28 
23 29 30 31 32 33 
23 34 35 36 37 38 
24 25 26 27 28 29 
24 30 31 32 33 34 
24 35 36 37 38 39 
25 26 27 28 29 30 
25 31 32 33 34 35 
26 27 28 29 30 31 
26 32 33 34 35 36 
27 28 29 30 31 32 
27 33 34 35 36 37 
28 29 30 31 32 33 
28 34 35 36 37 38 
29 30 31 32 33 34 
29 35 36 37 38 39 
Total = 128
```

---

**EDIT:** *New **correct** method to get combinations with ONE repeated element*

```
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Combinations with ONE repeated element:
echo/

rem Initialize output file and available numbers
rem/> lines.txt
set "avail= "
for /L %%n in (2,1,39) do set "avail=!avail!%%n "
set /A numAvail=38, lines=0, base=0

:nextBase
   set /A base+=1

   :nextLine
      set "line= %base% "

      if %base% gtr 1 (

         rem Initialize available numbers
         set "avail= "
         for /L %%n in (1,1,39) do set "avail=!avail!%%n "
         set "numAvail=39"

         rem Remove available numbers that appears in previous lines for this base number
         for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:" %base% " lines.txt') do (
            for %%b in (%%a) do if "!avail!" neq "!avail: %%b = !" (
               set "avail=!avail: %%b = !" & set /A numAvail-=1
            )
         )

      )

      rem Insert 5 numbers taking they from available ones
      set "nums=0"
      for /L %%n in (1,1,5) do if !numAvail! neq 0 (
         for /F "tokens=1*" %%x in ("!avail!") do (
            set "line=!line!%%x " & set "avail= %%y" & set /A nums+=1, numAvail-=1

            rem Remove available numbers that appears in previous lines for this new number
            for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:" %%x " lines.txt') do (
               for %%b in (%%a) do if "!avail!" neq "!avail: %%b = !" (
                  set "avail=!avail: %%b = !" & set /A numAvail-=1
               )
            )

         )
      )

      if %nums% equ 5 (
         echo %line%
         >> lines.txt echo %line%
         set /A lines+=1
      )

   if %numAvail% geq 5 goto nextLine

if %base% lss 34 goto nextBase

echo/
echo %lines% lines created
```

Output:

```
Combinations with ONE repeated element:

 1 2 3 4 5 6
 1 7 8 9 10 11
 1 12 13 14 15 16
 1 17 18 19 20 21
 1 22 23 24 25 26
 1 27 28 29 30 31
 1 32 33 34 35 36
 2 7 12 17 22 27
 2 8 13 18 23 28
 2 9 14 19 24 29
 2 10 15 20 25 30
 2 11 16 21 26 31
 3 7 13 19 25 31
 3 8 12 20 24 32
 4 7 14 18 26 30
 4 8 15 17 29 33
 5 7 15 21 23 32
 6 7 16 20 28 33
 7 24 34 37 38 39
 8 5 14 22 31 34
 9 3 15 18 22 35
 10 3 14 17 23 36
 12 4 9 21 25 28
 12 5 10 18 29 37
 13 4 10 22 32 38
 14 6 11 25 27 32
 17 5 9 13 26 39
 22 6 19 30 36 37
 31 4 20 23 35 37

29 lines created
```

---

**EDIT:** *Results of my new (I hope correct) method for combinations with TWO repeated numbers*

```
1- 1 2 3 4 5 6 
2- 1 2 7 8 9 10 
3- 1 2 11 12 13 14 
4- 1 2 15 16 17 18 
5- 1 2 19 20 21 22 
6- 1 2 23 24 25 26 
7- 1 2 27 28 29 30 
8- 1 2 31 32 33 34 
9- 1 2 35 36 37 38 
10- 1 3 7 11 15 19 
11- 1 3 8 12 16 20 
12- 1 3 9 13 17 21 
13- 1 3 10 14 18 22 
14- 1 3 23 27 31 35 
15- 1 3 24 28 32 36 
16- 1 3 25 29 33 37 
17- 1 3 26 30 34 38 
18- 1 4 7 12 17 22 
19- 1 4 8 11 18 21 
20- 1 4 9 14 15 20 
21- 1 4 10 13 16 19 
22- 1 4 23 28 33 38 
23- 1 4 24 27 34 37 
24- 1 4 25 30 31 36 
25- 1 4 26 29 32 35 
26- 1 5 7 13 18 20 
27- 1 5 8 14 17 19 
28- 1 5 9 11 16 22 
29- 1 5 10 12 15 21 
30- 1 5 23 29 34 36 
31- 1 5 24 30 33 35 
32- 1 5 25 27 32 38 
33- 1 5 26 28 31 37 
34- 1 6 7 14 16 21 
35- 1 6 8 13 15 22 
36- 1 6 9 12 18 19 
37- 1 6 10 11 17 20 
38- 1 6 23 30 32 37 
39- 1 6 24 29 31 38 
40- 1 6 25 28 34 35 
41- 1 6 26 27 33 36 
42- 2 3 7 12 18 21 
43- 2 3 8 11 17 22 
44- 2 3 9 14 16 19 
45- 2 3 10 13 15 20 
46- 2 3 23 28 34 37 
47- 2 3 24 27 33 38 
48- 2 3 25 30 32 35 
49- 2 3 26 29 31 36 
50- 2 4 7 11 16 20 
51- 2 4 8 12 15 19 
52- 2 4 9 13 18 22 
53- 2 4 10 14 17 21 
54- 2 4 23 27 32 36 
55- 2 4 24 28 31 35 
56- 2 4 25 29 34 38 
57- 2 4 26 30 33 37 
58- 2 5 7 14 15 22 
59- 2 5 8 13 16 21 
60- 2 5 9 12 17 20 
61- 2 5 10 11 18 19 
62- 2 5 23 30 31 38 
63- 2 5 24 29 32 37 
64- 2 5 25 28 33 36 
65- 2 5 26 27 34 35 
66- 2 6 7 13 17 19 
67- 2 6 8 14 18 20 
68- 2 6 9 11 15 21 
69- 2 6 10 12 16 22 
70- 2 6 23 29 33 35 
71- 2 6 24 30 34 36 
72- 2 6 25 27 31 37 
73- 2 6 26 28 32 38 
74- 3 4 7 8 13 14 
75- 3 4 9 10 11 12 
76- 3 4 15 16 21 22 
77- 3 4 17 18 19 20 
78- 3 4 23 24 29 30 
79- 3 4 25 26 27 28 
80- 3 4 31 32 37 38 
81- 3 4 33 34 35 36 
82- 3 5 7 9 23 25 
83- 3 5 8 10 24 26 
84- 3 5 11 13 27 29 
85- 3 5 12 14 28 30 
86- 3 5 15 17 31 33 
87- 3 5 16 18 32 34 
88- 3 5 19 21 35 37 
89- 3 5 20 22 36 38 
90- 3 6 7 10 27 30 
91- 3 6 8 9 28 29 
92- 3 6 11 14 23 26 
93- 3 6 12 13 24 25 
94- 3 6 15 18 35 38 
95- 3 6 16 17 36 37 
96- 3 6 19 22 31 34 
97- 3 6 20 21 32 33 
98- 3 7 16 24 31 39 
99- 3 8 15 23 32 39 
100- 4 5 7 10 28 29 
101- 4 5 8 9 27 30 
102- 4 5 11 14 24 25 
103- 4 5 12 13 23 26 
104- 4 5 15 18 36 37 
105- 4 5 16 17 35 38 
106- 4 5 19 22 32 33 
107- 4 5 20 21 31 34 
108- 4 6 7 9 24 26 
109- 4 6 8 10 23 25 
110- 4 6 11 13 28 30 
111- 4 6 12 14 27 29 
112- 4 6 15 17 32 34 
113- 4 6 16 18 31 33 
114- 4 6 19 21 36 38 
115- 4 6 20 22 35 37 
116- 4 9 16 23 34 39 
117- 4 10 15 24 33 39 
118- 4 32 7 18 25 39 
119- 5 6 7 8 11 12 
120- 5 6 9 10 13 14 
121- 5 6 15 16 19 20 
122- 5 6 17 18 21 22 
123- 5 6 23 24 27 28 
124- 5 6 25 26 29 30 
125- 5 6 31 32 35 36 
126- 5 6 33 34 37 38 
127- 5 34 7 17 24 39 
128- 6 19 8 24 32 39 
129- 6 20 7 23 31 39 
130- 7 8 15 16 25 26 
131- 7 8 17 18 23 27 
132- 7 8 19 20 28 30 
133- 7 8 21 22 24 29 
134- 7 9 11 13 31 32 
135- 7 9 12 14 33 34 
136- 7 9 15 17 28 35 
137- 7 9 16 18 29 30 
138- 7 9 19 21 27 39 
139- 7 10 11 14 35 36 
140- 7 10 12 13 37 38 
141- 7 10 15 18 31 34 
142- 7 10 16 17 32 33 
143- 7 10 19 22 23 26 
144- 7 11 17 21 25 30 
145- 7 11 18 22 28 33 
146- 7 12 15 20 24 27 
147- 7 13 15 21 23 33 
148- 7 13 16 22 27 34 
149- 7 14 17 20 26 29 
150- 7 14 18 19 24 37 
151- 8 7 31 33 35 37 
152- 8 7 32 34 36 38 
153- 8 9 11 14 37 38 
154- 8 9 12 13 35 36 
155- 8 9 15 18 24 33 
156- 8 10 11 13 33 34 
157- 8 10 12 14 31 32 
158- 8 10 15 17 29 30 
159- 8 10 16 18 28 35 
160- 8 11 15 20 31 36 
161- 8 11 16 19 23 29 
162- 8 12 17 21 26 28 
163- 8 12 18 22 25 30 
164- 8 12 23 24 34 37 
165- 8 13 17 20 24 38 
166- 8 13 18 19 26 31 
167- 8 14 15 21 27 34 
168- 8 14 16 22 33 36 
169- 8 21 3 25 31 38 
170- 8 22 4 26 34 39 
171- 9 5 15 26 32 39 
172- 9 10 15 16 27 36 
173- 9 10 17 18 25 26 
174- 9 10 19 20 24 29 
175- 9 10 21 22 28 30 
176- 9 10 23 31 33 37 
177- 9 11 17 19 33 36 
178- 9 11 18 20 23 27 
179- 9 12 15 22 23 29 
180- 9 12 16 21 24 31 
181- 9 13 15 19 25 30 
182- 9 13 16 20 26 28 
183- 9 14 17 22 24 27 
184- 9 14 18 21 32 35 
185- 9 16 6 25 32 38 
186- 9 22 3 26 33 35 
187- 10 11 15 22 25 32 
188- 10 11 16 21 26 37 
189- 10 12 17 19 27 34 
190- 10 12 18 20 33 36 
191- 10 13 17 22 31 35 
192- 10 13 18 21 24 27 
193- 10 13 23 28 32 36 
194- 10 14 15 19 28 38 
195- 10 14 16 20 23 30 
196- 10 19 3 25 36 39 
197- 11 12 15 16 28 34 
198- 11 12 17 18 24 29 
199- 11 12 19 20 25 26 
200- 11 12 21 22 27 35 
201- 11 12 23 30 33 39 
202- 11 13 15 17 26 39 
203- 11 13 16 18 25 36 
204- 11 17 4 23 31 37 
205- 11 20 3 24 34 35 
206- 11 20 5 28 32 39 
207- 12 5 16 25 37 39 
208- 12 14 15 17 25 36 
209- 12 14 16 18 26 38 
210- 13 14 15 16 24 29 
211- 13 14 17 18 28 33 
212- 13 14 19 20 27 32 
213- 13 14 21 22 25 26 
214- 13 15 4 27 31 38 
215- 13 21 4 29 37 39 
216- 14 16 4 28 32 37 
217- 16 19 7 12 35 36 
218- 16 20 17 21 27 39 
219- 16 22 17 19 25 28 
220- 18 5 8 29 38 39 
221- 18 20 15 21 25 28 
222- 18 22 15 19 27 39 
223- 21 22 23 31 32 36 
224- 23 27 10 29 38 39 
225- 23 38 3 12 17 19 
226- 24 26 11 22 30 31 
227- 24 29 25 27 35 36 
228- 24 29 26 28 33 34 
229- 25 30 10 24 37 38 
230- 28 29 11 14 21 31
```

Comment: Wowwa, thank you so much!  and 1h50... the first script took perhaps 5 minutes to get to 100.  But you're right, the real question is one that you asked: How many sets with 1 repetition can be assembled?"  There are a total of (39 choose 6) about 3 million sets.  There are only 6 that repeat none (relative to any one set).  There should be (39x38/6=) 247 sets (relative to any one starting set) that have just 1 number in common between any two sets.  With 2 in common, it goes up.

Comment: Yes, of course; _"that can be generated under precise rules in a very fast way"_. I am somewhat advanced in this solution. However, is the 1:26 am here and I want go to bed... I´ll complete this method tomorrow!  **`;)`**

Comment: Check the new (partial) result in my code. It seems you were wrong in the number of sets with ONE repetition: my new program generated 128 sets (not 247)...

Comment: Excel seems to be frizzing on me right now, but visually, lines 1 and 15 of the second set (with one repetition) have 4 in common: (1) 1 2 3 4 5 6; (15) 3 4 5 6 7 8 -- so far, the random way, it's yielding 22 with 1 rep (in an hour) and 145 with 2 reps.  I wasn't able to change the code to take out the randoms (it's severely above my level--literally Chinese is easier) BUT I was able to keep a running output file, so even it closes, I can still see the last values.  So far they're at 22 and 145

Comment: Ok, let's leave Excel outside this discussion, just the results of Batch file... Yes, the method I used to generate ONE repetition sets is wrong, but I think that the right method will generate even _less_ sets than 128... We can not use a method based on %random% and just take out the random parts, A method with no random is _entirely different_ than the former. I will work on this matter now and report as soon as I have news

Comment: morning, there are 171 (rep2) and 26 (rep1) after 12 hours with random -- I'd love to know how many there actually are, but 171 is enough

Comment: _"it is much more important to clearly define the problem's solution first, before waste more CPU time in a not useful code"_... See my new *correct* method to generate combinations with ONE repeated element that generated 29 lines in a few seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253619/discussion-between-rene-and-aacini).

Answer (score 1):

I posted a new answer here because the previous one is too large and don't accept any further text.

This problem is complex and convoluted because the number of input data is *huge* (3,262,623 possible combinations)! There are two ways to solve this problem: "brute force" methods (like Magoo's one) or "smart" methods that avoids to process the entire input set (like the mine). To have a better understanding of *the time* that brute force methods requires, run first this small program that show 3,262,623 numbers:

```
@echo off
set "start=%time%"
for /L %%i in (1,1,3262623) do echo %%i
echo Start: %start%
echo End:   %time%
```

Note that this program *just generates* the numbers. In a real solution, the numbers must be combined in groups of 6 with no repetitions *and* complete all the required additional tests, so the time *increases*.

Now run this program that just show the same numbers, but uses a "goto assembled loop" (like Magoo's program):

```
@echo off
set "start=%time%"
set number=0
:nextNum
set /A number+=1
echo %number%
if %number% lss 3262623 goto nextNum
echo Start: %start%
echo End:   %time%
```

You should understand that "brute force" methods are just unnaceptable if you want to generate a complete and real solution (even if they are translated to Phyton or any other language)...

Below are the last (corrected) results generated by the last version of my program. Please, note that the problem is complex and convoluted, so a "smart" method that solve it is difficult to develop. Perhaps it still have small bugs that can be fixed. IMPORTANT: please note that this method generates *all solutions* **in 15 minutes**! (Yes: fifteen minutes). So, if you want a *real solution* to your problem, it is much better to try to fix all details in this method instead of try to make faster the "brute force" one. Please, review the 215 result and report any problem...

```
1-  01 02 03 04 05 06 
2-  01 02 07 08 09 10 
3-  01 02 11 12 13 14 
4-  01 02 15 16 17 18 
5-  01 02 19 20 21 22 
6-  01 02 23 24 25 26 
7-  01 02 27 28 29 30 
8-  01 02 31 32 33 34 
9-  01 02 35 36 37 38 
10-  01 03 07 11 15 19 
11-  01 03 08 12 16 20 
12-  01 03 09 13 17 21 
13-  01 03 10 14 18 22 
14-  01 03 23 27 31 35 
15-  01 03 24 28 32 36 
16-  01 03 25 29 33 37 
17-  01 03 26 30 34 38 
18-  01 04 07 12 17 22 
19-  01 04 08 11 18 21 
20-  01 04 09 14 15 20 
21-  01 04 10 13 16 19 
22-  01 04 23 28 33 38 
23-  01 04 24 27 34 37 
24-  01 04 25 30 31 36 
25-  01 04 26 29 32 35 
26-  01 05 07 13 18 20 
27-  01 05 08 14 17 19 
28-  01 05 09 11 16 22 
29-  01 05 10 12 15 21 
30-  01 05 23 29 34 36 
31-  01 05 24 30 33 35 
32-  01 05 25 27 32 38 
33-  01 05 26 28 31 37 
34-  01 06 07 14 16 21 
35-  01 06 08 13 15 22 
36-  01 06 09 12 18 19 
37-  01 06 10 11 17 20 
38-  01 06 23 30 32 37 
39-  01 06 24 29 31 38 
40-  01 06 25 28 34 35 
41-  01 06 26 27 33 36 
42-  02 03 07 12 18 21 
43-  02 03 08 11 17 22 
44-  02 03 09 14 16 19 
45-  02 03 10 13 15 20 
46-  02 03 23 28 34 37 
47-  02 03 24 27 33 38 
48-  02 03 25 30 32 35 
49-  02 03 26 29 31 36 
50-  02 04 07 11 16 20 
51-  02 04 08 12 15 19 
52-  02 04 09 13 18 22 
53-  02 04 10 14 17 21 
54-  02 04 23 27 32 36 
55-  02 04 24 28 31 35 
56-  02 04 25 29 34 38 
57-  02 04 26 30 33 37 
58-  02 05 07 14 15 22 
59-  02 05 08 13 16 21 
60-  02 05 09 12 17 20 
61-  02 05 10 11 18 19 
62-  02 05 23 30 31 38 
63-  02 05 24 29 32 37 
64-  02 05 25 28 33 36 
65-  02 05 26 27 34 35 
66-  02 06 07 13 17 19 
67-  02 06 08 14 18 20 
68-  02 06 09 11 15 21 
69-  02 06 10 12 16 22 
70-  02 06 23 29 33 35 
71-  02 06 24 30 34 36 
72-  02 06 25 27 31 37 
73-  02 06 26 28 32 38 
74-  03 04 07 08 13 14 
75-  03 04 09 10 11 12 
76-  03 04 15 16 21 22 
77-  03 04 17 18 19 20 
78-  03 04 23 24 29 30 
79-  03 04 25 26 27 28 
80-  03 04 31 32 37 38 
81-  03 04 33 34 35 36 
82-  03 05 07 09 23 25 
83-  03 05 08 10 24 26 
84-  03 05 11 13 27 29 
85-  03 05 12 14 28 30 
86-  03 05 15 17 31 33 
87-  03 05 16 18 32 34 
88-  03 05 19 21 35 37 
89-  03 05 20 22 36 38 
90-  03 06 07 10 27 30 
91-  03 06 08 09 28 29 
92-  03 06 11 14 23 26 
93-  03 06 12 13 24 25 
94-  03 06 15 18 35 38 
95-  03 06 16 17 36 37 
96-  03 06 19 22 31 34 
97-  03 06 20 21 32 33 
98-  03 07 16 24 31 39 
99-  03 08 15 23 32 39 
100-  04 05 07 10 28 29 
101-  04 05 08 09 27 30 
102-  04 05 11 14 24 25 
103-  04 05 12 13 23 26 
104-  04 05 15 18 36 37 
105-  04 05 16 17 35 38 
106-  04 05 19 22 32 33 
107-  04 05 20 21 31 34 
108-  04 06 07 09 24 26 
109-  04 06 08 10 23 25 
110-  04 06 11 13 28 30 
111-  04 06 12 14 27 29 
112-  04 06 15 17 32 34 
113-  04 06 16 18 31 33 
114-  04 06 19 21 36 38 
115-  04 06 20 22 35 37 
116-  04 09 16 23 34 39 
117-  04 10 15 24 33 39 
118-  04 32 07 18 25 39 
119-  05 06 07 08 11 12 
120-  05 06 09 10 13 14 
121-  05 06 15 16 19 20 
122-  05 06 17 18 21 22 
123-  05 06 23 24 27 28 
124-  05 06 25 26 29 30 
125-  05 06 31 32 35 36 
126-  05 06 33 34 37 38 
127-  06 21 08 24 35 39 
128-  06 22 07 23 36 39 
129-  07 08 15 16 25 26 
130-  07 08 17 18 23 24 
131-  07 08 19 20 27 28 
132-  07 08 21 22 29 30 
133-  07 09 11 13 31 32 
134-  07 09 12 14 33 34 
135-  07 09 15 17 27 29 
136-  07 09 16 18 28 30 
137-  07 10 11 14 35 36 
138-  07 10 12 13 37 38 
139-  07 10 15 18 31 34 
140-  07 10 16 17 32 33 
141-  07 10 19 21 23 26 
142-  07 10 20 22 24 25 
143-  07 11 17 21 25 28 
144-  07 11 18 22 26 27 
145-  07 12 15 20 23 30 
146-  07 12 16 19 29 35 
147-  07 13 15 21 24 36 
148-  07 14 17 20 26 31 
149-  08 07 31 33 35 37 
150-  08 07 32 34 36 38 
151-  08 09 11 14 37 38 
152-  08 09 12 13 35 36 
153-  08 10 11 13 33 34 
154-  08 10 12 14 31 32 
155-  08 10 15 17 28 30 
156-  08 10 16 18 27 29 
157-  08 10 19 22 35 38 
158-  08 10 20 21 36 37 
159-  08 11 15 20 24 29 
160-  08 11 16 19 23 30 
161-  08 12 17 21 26 27 
162-  08 12 18 22 25 28 
163-  08 13 17 20 25 32 
164-  08 13 18 19 26 31 
165-  08 17 04 29 31 39 
166-  09 10 15 16 35 37 
167-  09 10 17 18 25 26 
168-  09 10 19 20 29 30 
169-  09 10 21 22 27 28 
170-  09 10 23 24 31 36 
171-  09 11 17 19 24 33 
172-  09 11 18 20 23 35 
173-  09 11 25 27 34 36 
174-  09 12 15 22 24 32 
175-  09 12 16 21 25 31 
176-  09 13 15 19 23 28 
177-  09 13 16 20 24 27 
178-  09 14 17 22 23 30 
179-  09 14 18 21 24 29 
180-  09 18 03 27 37 39 
181-  10 12 17 19 34 36 
182-  10 14 15 19 25 27 
183-  10 14 16 20 23 28 
184-  10 21 03 25 34 39 
185-  11 12 15 16 27 28 
186-  11 12 17 18 29 30 
187-  11 12 19 20 25 26 
188-  11 12 21 22 23 33 
189-  11 13 15 17 26 35 
190-  11 13 16 18 25 37 
191-  11 14 15 18 32 33 
192-  12 06 15 26 31 39 
193-  13 14 15 16 29 30 
194-  13 14 17 18 27 28 
195-  13 14 19 20 33 35 
196-  13 14 21 22 25 26 
197-  13 14 23 24 32 34 
198-  13 14 31 36 37 39 
199-  14 05 16 26 33 39 
200-  15 20 17 21 38 39 
201-  16 18 12 14 36 38 
202-  16 20 17 22 29 34 
203-  16 21 10 11 24 38 
204-  17 05 07 30 34 39 
205-  17 20 23 27 33 37 
206-  18 21 10 13 30 32 
207-  18 22 15 19 29 39 
208-  20 22 08 09 26 33 
209-  24 26 11 28 34 39 
210-  24 26 12 14 35 37 
211-  27 29 19 21 31 32 
212-  27 29 20 25 35 39 
213-  27 30 11 14 20 21 
214-  27 30 12 13 19 22 
215-  33 38 07 11 29 39
```

**EDIT:** *New "Brute force" method*

I wrote a "Brute force" program that generates each one of the 3,262,623 combinations and, for each one, count the number of repeated elements versus all previously generated valid combinations and, if the number is less or equal 2, generate a new valid combination.

Although the method is "brute force", it is programmed in the fastest possible way. The program is simple enough to be understood even if you don't know too much about Batch files, so you can modify the last number and the max number of repetitions in a very simple way. However, note that the numbers in each combination (6 in this case) is *hard programmed* in the code, although you could also modify it via a careful review of the other lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem "Brute force" method to get all combinations of N numbers in sets of 6 elements
rem with a maximum of Rep repetitions

rem Set last number and max number of repetitions
set /A n=39, rep=2
rem In this version the number of elements in combination is fixed to 6!

set /A nM1=n-1, nM2=n-2, nM3=n-3, nM4=n-4, nM5=n-5,  lines=1
set "c[1,2,3,4,5,6]=1"
echo 1- 1,2,3,4,5,6
> lines.txt echo 1,2,3,4,5,6
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
set "start=%time:~0,-3%"

< NUL (
for /L %%i in (1,1,%nM5%) do (
   echo !time:~0,-3!          
   set /A iP1=%%i+1
   for /L %%j in (!iP1!,1,%nM4%) do (
      set /A jP1=%%j+1
      for /L %%k in (!jP1!,1,%nM3%) do (
         set /A kP1=%%k+1
         for /L %%l in (!kP1!,1,%nM2%) do (
            set /A lP1=%%l+1
            for /L %%m in (!lP1!,1,%nM1%) do (
               set /A mP1=%%m+1
               for /L %%n in (!mP1!,1,%n%) do (
                  set /P "=%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n      !CR!"
                  set "reps=0"
                  for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set c[') do (
                     if !reps! leq %rep% (
                        for %%b in (%%a) do set /A "reps+=^!(%%b-%%i)+^!(%%b-%%j)+^!(%%b-%%k)+^!(%%b-%%l)+^!(%%b-%%m)+^!(%%b-%%n)"
                        if !reps! leq %rep% set "reps=0"
                     )
                  )
                  if !reps! leq %rep% (
                     set "c[%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n]=1"
                     set /A lines+=1
                     echo !lines!- %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n      
                     >> lines.txt echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n
                  )
               )
            )
         )
      )
   )
))

echo Start: %start%
echo End:   %time:~0,-3%
```

Comment: The results are perfect (within 2 repeats)!  And the method is sleek.  To help awareness and future readers, this list is a complete list of a set of 6 numbers wiherein any two sets of 6 have a maximum of two repeating numbers between them.  BUT, it is not the only such set, and that's what makes this program so hard to write.  This set is the natural set.  It starts with the number "1", builds the natural first set (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and then continues to include only sets that have less than 2 same nums.  If the first set were, eg 1, 5, 7, 19, 21, 35, a completely different list results.

Comment: It turns out there's a bunch of math theory about these "lists", I guess they're called "block chains" in math (I always just though that related to bitcoin somehow)--didn't really know what it was.  I'm not sure how many subsets of the whole exist.  The natural set which you found has 215.  I've let the random one run a few days now and it's stalled at 183.  Just like the first rep, your natural set was 29 long and my random one (which is still stuck) only made it to 26.  So it seems like they're also not all the same length, either--which makes sense since 39 isn't evenly divisible by 6.

Comment: It seems there are at least (39 C 6)/215 = 15,174 different subsets, each complete, that could be generated depending on the starting value and if a sequential build is used, needs to include the numbers under as well as over the set starting point.

Comment: To answer the question of the optimization of the random function, then, a first random set would need to be generated, and then a sequential list (developed in 15 minutes from the random set), and then--after having the list of relative sets--a random set could be taken from the list (after it's generated).  After the initial 15 minutes of building, it'd be a lightening fast program, but also limited in scope to 
a subset of the whole.

Comment: Hi! I did a small modification in the code that results in slightly _more lines_ (247 now). Could you check that these new 247 lines are correct? The good news are that the new code is **faster**! 11 minutes now!!!  **`:)`**

Comment: Hi from Taiwan!  Really good try, and it's appreciated!  I pasted the list of 103 lines (103 of the 247 repeated 3 or more numbers with at least one other line) with 2 examples but the comment box complained ("Too long by 3600 characters") -- I'm guessing the specific lines didn't matter.  Line 3 with 247 was the first, then 6 with 234.  Did you want the details?

Comment: Would it be difficult to change the code to work with sets of 4 numbers that repeat at most (1) one number and (2) two numbers?  I'm currently using random lists of those sets.  I have a list of 98 lines of sets of 4 that allow a maximum repeat of 1, and 1799 lines of sets of 4 that allow a max repeat of 2.  They've been generating 6 days, the 4r1 list of 98 stopped growing on the first day; the 4r2 list of (currently) 1799 added 5 more in the last 24 hours.  I can confirm duplicates in lists using Excel, but I don't have the ability (except randomly) to build lists.  And yours are natural! :)

Comment: OK. I can see the problem. This means that the faster method is not reliable. I'm going to remove the list of 245 wrong combinations from my answer. I'm adjusting the original code to start from numbers other than (1,2). Note that you can't set a start like (1, 5, 7, 19, 21, 35); you should set the entire initial set of 39 numbers, but in this case I'm not sure how to detect when the process should end. The modified program generated an extra line: **216- 37,38,15,19,24,30**

Comment: After the modified code is correct, I'll try to modify it in order to accept a different number of elements and repeated elements. Again: be aware that the solution of this problem via random numbers is NOT reliable. As a larger number of results is obtained it is more difficult to generate a new result. You could run the random method for years and perhaps it will not give _all_ the results. In this case, it would be better to generate _all_ the 3,262,623 possible combinations and check they one by one. Perhaps doing this would take less time than the time you already run the random method...

Comment: Check the new "Brute force" method added. I am pretty sure you like it! **`;)`**

Comment: Hi, I replied yesterday but in the other chat, line 216 is good

Comment: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10826