# Batch Script, amending a working script that generates sets of random numbers into one that generates all possible sets

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to amend a Batch Script file that generates sets of random numbers according to three conditions into a file that generates all the numbers of the condition (so that I can see how many there actually are).

The conditions are:
(1) (minn) and (maxn) are the minimum and maximum values of the numbers
(2) (setoff) = number of unique numbers in a set, e.g. a set of 6 numbers, setof=6
(3) (maxrep) = maximum repetitions between numbers of any other set

The current structure should be solid (it worked for random numbers); I think it's my syntax?

The original file generates random numbers, it was provided in the first answer at:
[Batch Script, need help generating lines of six different numbers (between 1 and 39) that have no more than 2 numbers in common with any previous line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219423/)

The goal is also to be able to change the values of "setof", "maxrep", and "minn" and "maxn" easily.  My best but not functional attempt:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: 
:: Script credit to Magoo, 2023.05.10:
:: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo
:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219423/
:: 
:: Script to find sets of (setof) X numbers
:: between a min (minn) and max (maxn) value, and
:: max repeititions (maxrep) between any two sets
::

SET a/ maxn=39
SET a/ minn=1
SET a/ maxrep=1
SET a/ setof=6

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="

SET #nextnum=0
SET #combos=0

:newcombo
SET /a #nums=0
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="
:newnum
SET /a nextnum+=1
IF %nextnum% gtr %maxn% SET %nextnum%=%minn%

:: keep single digits written with leading 0
SET /a nextnum=100+%nextnum%
SET "$%nextnum%=%nextnum:~-2%"

SET /a #nums+=1
IF %#nums% lss !setof! GOTO newnum
SET "#c="
FOR  /F "tokens=2delims==" %%e In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "#c=!#c!,%%e"
FOR /L %%y IN (1,1,%#combos%) DO (
 SET /a matchcount=0
 FOR %%o IN (!#c%%y!) DO IF DEFINED $1%%o set/a matchcount+=1
 IF !matchcount! gtr !maxrep! GOTO newcombo
)
SET /a #combos+=1

ECHO %#combos% generated : !#c! >> combos_v3_screen.txt

SET "#c%#combos%=%#c:~1%"
::not sure how many combos there are, ideally print all without missing any
IF %#combos% lss 29 GOTO newcombo
(
 FOR /L %%y IN (1,1,%#combos%) DO ECHO !#c%%y!
)>combos_v3.txt

TYPE combos_v3.txt

:: 
::GOTO :EOF
::delete extra files:
::  :del_get_files
::  for %%z in (combos_v3_screen.txt,list_delfilenames_etc.txt) do (
::      if exist "%%z" del /q /f "%%z"
::  )
::
::
GOTO :EOF
```

=====

combos_v3.txt (current):

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
```

=====

combos_v3.txt (expected):

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06
01, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11
01, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
01, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21
01, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26
01, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31
01, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
02, 07, 12, 17, 22, 27
02, 08, 13, 18, 23, 28
02, 09, 14, 19, 24, 29
02, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30
02, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31
03, 07, 13, 19, 25, 31
03, 08, 12, 20, 24, 32
03, 09, 15, 18, 22, 35
03, 10, 14, 17, 23, 36
04, 07, 14, 18, 26, 30
04, 08, 15, 17, 29, 33
04, 09, 12, 21, 25, 28
04, 10, 13, 22, 32, 38
04, 20, 23, 31, 35, 37
05, 07, 15, 21, 23, 32
05, 08, 14, 22, 31, 34
05, 09, 13, 17, 26, 39
05, 10, 12, 18, 29, 37
06, 07, 16, 20, 28, 33
06, 11, 14, 25, 27, 32
06, 19, 22, 30, 36, 37
07, 24, 34, 37, 38, 39
```

Credit to [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) for the list of expected values (setof=6, maxrep=1, minn=1, maxn=1)

Comment: are you actually trying to generate all sets, are just ensure no duplicates within the generated sets. this looks alot like a set of lotto numbers.
If your actually trying to generate all possible combinations, prepare to wait a very long while.

Comment: definitely not all possible combinations, that'd be a lot, and a lot for the different max/mins and sets.  Mostly in need of "random" enough sample of the whole set (random, in the sense that a set of 6 numbers with one repetition between any two sets would be one of a number of subsets of the whole, each subset having a relative maximum--maxreps--between them).

Comment: It's part of a project in the unconscious (or superconscious) identification of patterns.  I'm not in the field of computers and not sure how to get the lists, especially complete lists such as the set of 6 with one rep above.

Comment: the basic steps you'll need to take is to: After generating each number but the first,  check the current list of numbers for presence of the Random number before appending it, if it's not already in that string, append it, else generate the number again. Upon completion of the string reaching the desired set size, sort it. If the output file exists, check it for the presence of the sorted string. if it's present, generate the string from scatch, else append the string to the output, and increment a counter for the number of strings generated.

Comment: Use an if condition to end processing after reaching the desired number of generations.

Comment: This is the only part I'm unclear of your intentions with: `(3) (maxrep) = maximum repetitions between numbers of any other set` Is this a constraint you want to impose - IE Ensure the generated number has no more than `n`  numbers in common with any other set? Or do you wnat to allow generation of such, and simply find how many generated sets meet that criteria

Comment: It's a constraint selected (set) into the code manually before the run, "no more than n numbers in common with any other set" -- yes, exactly that

Comment: just to be clear, though, I'm not looking to generate a list with random numbers--any list generated (for whatever maxrep, min/max, etc) is not with random numbers.  That script is already in place, and already working

Comment: i.e. I'm trying to use the random-generating script to simply swap out the "random number get function" with a "test the next number in the list of all possible of the whole set (millions) and keep it if meets the criteria, criteria (maxrep) tested against all other kept values as well"

Comment: I'm wondering then why you dont just use nested `for /l` loops structured in such a way to avoid that conditional repat circumstance in order to generate the desired output

Comment: The first time I visited China, I saw everyone eating rice with chopsticks.  Even training what I considered really young kids in the art of shoveling rice with two sticks from the end of a small bowl hurriedly into open mouths as though time itself weren't sufficient to use a spoon.  No one used a spoon.  I still use a spoon.  What you just asked, is so far from my current ability and knowledge that you might as well be describing a spoon to people programmed to use two insanely inconvenient sticks.  I'm dearly sorry... I'm really dumb when it comes to CS :S

Comment: "I'm wondering then why you dont just use nested for /l loops structured in such a way to avoid that conditional repat circumstance in order to generate the desired output " noted